# GestureDetector and exclusive activation while calling onTap in a widget list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a simple vertical scrolling calendar.
Problem is that I can't manage to find a way to reset back to previous state in case I tap on a new container.

Here's the code:

```
class CalendarBox extends StatelessWidget {
  BoxProprieties boxProprieties = BoxProprieties();
  Map item;
  CalendarBox({this.item});
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Producer>(
      builder: (context, producer, child) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print(item['dateTime']);
          selected = producer.selectedState(selected);
        },
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          color: selected == true ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey[200],
          height: 80,
          width: 50,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                '${item['dayNum']}',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: boxProprieties.dayColor(item['dateTime'])),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Here's the situation:

Comment: What do you mean by "reset back to the previous state in case"?

Comment: Did you mean that the previous one should return to grey on selecting a new one?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it is, create a model for boxes and keep a value current selected block, in your model you will have the index assigned to that block,

---

```
int currentSelected =1; //initial value
```

---

```
class Block{
 int id;
  ..
  .. // any other stuff
 }
```

---

now in your code, the check modifies to

---

```
block.id == currentSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey[200],
```

---

your on tap modifies to

---

```
   onTap: () {
      setState(){
             currentSelected = block.id
         };
    },
```

If you want to prevent the rebuild of the whole thing every time you can use [valueNotifire](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) for current selected block. Hope this gives you an idea.